# Best Way to Write Bytes in the Middle of a File in Java

Tags: java, file, java-io

What is the best way to write bytes in the middle of a file using Java?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reading and Writing in the middle of a file is as simple as using a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in Java.

[`RandomAccessFile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), despite its name, is more like an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and less like a `File`.  It allows you to read or seek through `bytes` in a file and then begin writing over whichever bytes you care to stop at.

Once you discover this class, it is very easy to use if you have a basic understanding of regular file i/o.

A small example:

```
public static void aMethod(){
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("whereDidIPutTHatFile"), "rw");
    long aPositionWhereIWantToGo = 99;
    f.seek(aPositionWhereIWantToGo); // this basically reads n bytes in the file
    f.write("Im in teh fil, writn bites".getBytes());
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: what if i do not know the position or if i have hundreds of files where i have to insert data in the middle of them after some specified text?

Comment: If you do not know the position, then you need to open the file and read it to find where you need to write.

Comment: my "file.txt" contains text like this "hi how you (newline) I am fine thanks" now i want to insert "are" in the middle of the text what i have to do? while doing this please mind that we are working with high amount of sized files

Comment: Note that the RandomAccessFile would overwrite the current content of the file from aPositionWhereIWantToGo

Answer (score 6):

Use `RandomAccessFile`

- [Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)
- [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: The tutorial linked to doesn't actually mention the RandomAccessFile class. Maybe this one instead: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in write mode without truncating it, seek to the desired offset, and write the desired data.  Just be careful about text/binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s best to create file chunks every time. And when the file is downloaded, connect them together. Now I'm working on it.