# How to delete a data from a file through java?

Tags: java, java-io

I want to read a file in java. And then, I want to delete a line from that file without the file being re-written.

How can I do this?

Someone suggested me to read/write to a file without the file being re-written with the help of RandomAccessFile. [How to write data to a file through java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984534/how-to-write-data-to-a-file-through-java)

Specifically, that files contains lines. One line contains three field - id, name and profession - separated by \t. I want to read that file through a Reader or InputStream or any other way and then search for a line that has the specified keyword (say 121) and then wants to delete that whole line.

This operation needs to be performed without the whole file being re-written

Comment: `RandomAccessFile` does not allow you to _insert_ bytes in the middle of a file stream; it merely _overwrites_ bytes. That's why it doesn't need to rewrite the file. If you want to insert or delete stuff in the middle of a file, you need to shift everything else over to make room.

Comment: ...and if you're deleting the 1st line, that means you're effectively rewriting the whole file. Also, what to do about the no-longer-needed data at the end of the file when you've done your shift? Good question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can alter a file on a filesystem in any way without writing to it, including deleting a line.

Do you mean you want to write the file without altering the file's metadata, like the last modified time?

---

Based on your updated question:

I don't think you can do what you're asking to do here. You can't remove bytes from a file once the file has been written, note no deleteByte or removeByte methods in [RandomAccessFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

I suggest moving the content of your file to a database - that allows this kind of record-oriented operation.

The alternative is, you have to rewrite the file. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

"Lines" are an abstract concept -- they're just an arbitrary sequence of bytes terminated by "\n". `BufferedWriters` and their ilk don't support textual editing in this way, so you'll have to rewrite the file in its entirety.

In general, what you want to do is:

- open a reader
- read content into some suitable data structure
- close the reader
- change data/records which need to be changed in this data structure
- open a `FileWriter` with `append == false`
- write content of data structure to resulting file
- close `FileWriter`

Answer (score 0):

add a marker in your lines saying if your line is deleted or not : this will make a software delete instead od a hardware delete.

if you have to insert new lines, you then can reuse those that are marked as deleted.

Answer (score -1):

The below code searchs the line or fields in a single text file reads the file line by line
then the line or fields can be replaced by " " or any other string. Here we use the pattern and Matcher classes.

If this not clearing your question do let me know.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class DeleteLine
{

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
    String line=null;
    File f = new File("d:/xyz.txt");

```
String replaceString=properties.getProperty("replaceAll.String");
```

;
               br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/giri/scjp/");

```
          while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )//BufferedReader contains readline method
  {

      Pattern p=Pattern.compile(searchString);/*here u an specify the line u want to delete */
      Matcher m=p.matcher(line);
      line=m.replaceAll(replaceString);/*here replace String u can " " so that it will be emptied */
      System.out.println(line);
    } 
      //System.out.println(line);
           } 

      }
```

}
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/xyz.txt"));
     String line = null;

}

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File couldnt find");

  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

}

Comment: Readability suggestion: "Indent [at least] four spaces to create an escaped <pre><code> block." http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help