# how to write to a new line of CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to benchmark sorting methods.  My writeCSV(String) method writes over the first line every time I call it.  Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    writeCSV("data size (100 times),bubble,insertion,merge,quick");

    sortRandomSet(20);
}

 public static void sortRandomSet(int setSize) throws Exception
{
    .
    .
    .
    writeCSV(setSize+","+bTime+","+mTime+","+iTime+","+qTime);
}
/*******************************************************************************
* writeCSV(course[]) method
* Last edited by Steve Pesce 3/19/2014 for CSci 112
* Writes String to CSV
* 
*/
public static void writeCSV(String line) throws Exception {

    //create new File object 
    java.io.File courseCSV = new java.io.File("benchmark.csv");

    //create PrintWriter object on new File object
    java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(courseCSV);

    outfile.write(line + "\n");

    outfile.close();
}//end writeCSV(String)
```

I want writeCSV to start on a new line every time it is called, is this possible to do?

Comment: I will use the append method because I have used it before;  The random access file seemed like a fine solution too.

Comment: If any of the answers helped to resolve the issue, please remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Had 1 min before i could accept when I wrote that.

Comment: All good. Just a friendly reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `append` method. This will append your input to the end of the file.

Comment: He wants to write over the first line.

Comment: No he doesn't. The last line says "I want writeCSV to start on a new line every time it is called"

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, right after your call function you can add a string to the first line, have you tried that?

Also, when you create a new file add "a" as an argument which stands for append.

Try using [`RandomAccessFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181408/best-way-to-write-bytes-in-the-middle-of-a-file-in-java), it should explain how to add things to selected line in a text file

Comment: When you write to a file, add a line of code that write to the first line, have a look at the link i added, it should explain how

Answer (score 1):

Use java.io.FileWriter instead:

```
java.io.FileWriter outfile = new java.io.FileWriter("benchmark.csv", true); //true = append
outfile.write(line+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "append method for this"

Comment: it should be a comment.